# Is the following application of Ito's formula correct?

Tags: stochastic-processes, change-of-variable, absolute-continuity

Suppose that $|\Lambda_t|$ is an $\mathbb{R}^d$-stochastic process with differential of $|\Lambda_t|^2$ being
\begin{align*} 
d |\Lambda_t|^2 
& = 2  e^{\delta  t } \langle G(U_t), \Lambda_t\rangle dt 
\end{align*}
where $\delta>0$ and $U_t$ is a given process.

Now fix $\theta>0$, apply Ito's formula to $f(x)= \sqrt{x+ \theta }$ and use the previous inequality, then:
\begin{align*}
|\Lambda_t |& \leq \sqrt{|\Lambda_t |^2+ \theta } \\
&  = \sqrt{|v|^2+\theta}+\int_0^t  \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\Lambda_s|^2+\theta}} e^{\delta s} \langle G(U_s), \Lambda_s\rangle  ds 
\end{align*}

Was the previous calculation correct? Could I apply Ito's formula to $f(x)= \sqrt{x+ \theta }$ even if it is not $\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ito's formula. Seems fine to me. By the way, $f\in C^\infty([0,\infty))$ (we don't need it for negative values of $x$).

Comment: So I imagine that one can use Ito's formula on subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ provided that the underlying process attains values in that subset, right @zhoraster ? So in my case on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Once more, Ito's formula is irrelevant: one uses it whenever the process in question has stochastic differentials, but your process has usual differential. Anyway, yes, it is safe to apply any change of variable formula to anything taking values in the domain where the function in question is smooth.

Comment: But why do you say that Ito is irrelevant: I calculate the stochastic differential  with Ito's formula: $$d\sqrt{|\Lambda_s|^2+\theta}  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\Lambda_s|^2+\theta}} e^{\delta s} \langle G(U_s), \Lambda_s\rangle$$

Comment: Using Ito's formula here is like using a helicopter to cross the street. When you have $dX_t = ... dt + ... dZ_t$, where $Z$ is a stochastic process, you use Ito's formula. But when it's just $...dt$ (no matter if the object behind dots is stochastic or not), you don't use it.

Comment: Ah well right of course, when I'm into stochastic calculus I just think about Ito's formula but of course it is more elegant to do as you say. Thanks!